# Concurrent firewalls

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-security

Context:
I am currently working on a site where some features are only available to authenticated members. So I have the following firewall configuration:

/app/config/security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        members:
            class:              VE\ProjectBundle\Model\Member
            algorithm:          sha1
            iterations:         1
            encode_as_base64:   false
    providers:
        members:
            propel:
                class:      VE\ProjectBundle\Model\Member
                property:   email
    firewalls:
        member_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider:   members
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:             /member
                check_path:             /member/validate-login
                username_parameter:     email
                password_parameter:     password
                default_target_path:    /member
            logout:
                path:   /member/logout
                target: /member
                invalidate_session: false
```

I also have an administration area accessible to the URL "/administration" and which the following configuration:

/app/config/security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        administrators:
            class:              VE\AdministrationBundle\Model\Administrator
            algorithm:          sha1
            iterations:         1
            encode_as_base64:   false
    providers:
        administrators:
            propel:
                class:      VE\AdministrationBundle\Model\Administrator
                property:   email
    firewalls:
        administration_area:
            pattern:    ^/administration
            provider:   administrators
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:             /administration/administrator/login
                check_path:             /administration/administrator/validate-login
                username_parameter:     email
                password_parameter:     password
                default_target_path:    /administration
                csrf_parameter:         _token
            logout:
                path:   /administration/administrator/logout
                target: /administration
                invalidate_session: false
    access_control:
        administration_administrator_login:
            path: ^/administration/administrator/login
            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
        administration:
            path: ^/administration
            roles: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Problem:
I want to show in the global template of the site (behind the firewall "member_area") a link to return to the administration when the visitor is authenticated to the firewall "administration_area". In fact, I try to do something more complex, but I simplified the problem to be more clear.

/src/VE/ProjectBundle/Resources/views/globalTemplate.html.twig:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <a href="#">Return to administration</a>
{% endif %}
```

Except that the pattern of the firewall is "/administration", or the firewall "administration_area" is not active for the URL "/home" for example. In addition, if "app.user" is defined, it will contain an object "Member" and not an object "Administrator".

Change the pattern of the firewall "administration_area" to "^/" does not solve anything because the firewall "member_area" is executed before.

Changing the order of firewalls in the configuration ask the opposite problem. If "app.user" is defined, it will contain an object "Administrator" and not an object "Member".

Share the same context between the two firewalls appears not to be either a solution because we have not a single object "User". I want absolutely to have two separate entities (Member and Administrator).

The solution seems to be an evolution of Symfony to allow the configuration of concurrent firewalls on same pattern. See my post here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16378

Do you have any ideas to solve my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need two separate entities? I would use the the same firewall and check for `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: My two entities are in different bundles and have in common that the properties related to authentication (email , password and salt) . I want to maintain this separation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is nothing wrong with defining the two firewalls, two user providers, etc.

What I don't fully understand is the problem with the template part. I would add the usual `is_granted(ROLE_ADMIN)` and `is_granted(ROLE_MEMBER)` checks in the template to display the corresponding links.

In my opinion, the template shouldn't care about which firewall the user logged in but which roles the logged user has. And don't worry about the security, because the "access_control" and the voters will always prevent access to any resource the user is not allowed to access to.

Comment: Calling `is_granted('ROLE_NAME')` is equivalent to calling "isGranted" method on the AuthorizationChecker service. The "isGranted" method is based on the current security token that can not be both a Member instance and an Administrator instance. The first firewall that match determines the security token. If it is the "member_area" firewall : my security token will always be a Member instance. And test the role "ROLE_ADMIN" it always returns false.